# Outlook - HTML tags issue

Tags: html, outlook

I have a question about why Microsoft Outlook is converting HTML tags. The email I am sending has the following code:

```html
<p><strong>Quisquam cognomina autemły condemnendus vestimentorum earum Sancta EODEM.Quoquo eu est hic discernere.</strong> Secretarius d necłorci regnante regressum y diam 3111/61/81 y recordationem consequatur: Nostramm: DEESSE OPPRESSU APPONEMUS - OPPRESSA
  QUOD: SED UNDE VACUUS AC E. w PROPANENDO id.RECOMPENSA E EAQUE: AC QUAS ARCU QUAM QUOS CRAS NEMO ASSUM: 000 000,00 NAM Egetł: Słsurdis ac dignitatem d justo. AVOCARE omnibus oppugnationem cras/augusti:</p>
<table border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      ....
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<p>D doloremque SEM PRAEDAM PERSONA AD ASSUM</p>
```

After sending the message, the Outlook email looks like this:

[image: Wrong table tag]

For some reason, Outlook is changing `</table>` to `&lt; /table&gt;`  - what could be causing this?